# Compute this integral by using lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I need to compute this integral:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \sin(x/n) dx$$

My attempt: I do
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \sin(x/n) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} e^{-x} \frac{x}{n}=  xe^{-x}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=xe^{-x}*0=0$$

So if I can apply LDCT, i.e., switch the limit and integral, then the answer will be 0.

To use LDCT, I define $f_n (x)=(1+ \frac{x}{n})^{-n} \sin(x/n) $, then I need to find $g(x)$ such that $|f_n (x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$. One potential $g(x)$, I guess, is $xe^{-x}$. And the $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}=1 < \infty$. So it satisfies $g(x) \in L^1(\mu)$. Then it justifies I can use LDCT. But I don't know how to show $f_n (x)=(1+ \frac{x}{n})^{-n} \sin(x/n) \leq (1+ \frac{x}{n})^{-n} \frac{x}{n} \leq xe^{-x}$. I am stuck on the last inequality.

Comment: Also using Bernoulli's inequality: $(1+x/n)^{n/2} \geqslant 1 + x/2$ which implies $(1+x/n)^{-n} \leqslant (1+x/2)^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x>0$. Let
$$ f(n)=(1+ \frac{x}{n})^{-n}. $$
Then
$$ f'(n)=(1+ \frac{x}{n})^{-n}\frac{1}{x+n}\bigg[x-(n+x)\ln\bigg(1+\frac{x}n\bigg)\bigg]. $$
Let
$$ g(n)=x-(n+x)\ln\bigg(1+\frac{x}n\bigg). $$
Then
$$ g'(n)=-\frac{x}{n}+\ln\bigg(1+\frac{x}n\bigg)<0 $$
which implies that $g(n)$ is decreasing. So, for $n<\infty$, $g(n)>g(\infty)=0$. Thus $f'(n)>0$ or $f(n)$ is increasing and then hence $f(n)<f(\infty)=e^{-x}$